# Getting highest and lowest selling items, just need idea

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, erd

I'm trying to find out of the lowest and highest selling products for each category of paint
products in each state during each quarter of the year.

This is my ERD:

[image: It is my ERD]

And that is the code I could write so far. My brain stopped. If you can say connect those tables, that will be enough for me. I didn't understand the logic of finding the selling products.

```
SELECT max(line.prod_sku) as Prod_SKU, brand_name, prod_category,
       sum(line.line_qty) as highest
from LGLINE line,
     LGPRODUCT prod,
     LGBRAND
where line.prod_sku = prod.prod_sku AND prod.Brand_ID = LGBRAND.Brand_ID
group by Prod_Category
```

it's my code so far

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Tip of today: Always use modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: You typically `GROUP BY` the same columns as you `SELECT`, except those who are arguments to set functions.

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using? Such ranking gets easy as of MySQL 8.

Comment: You have to select the sum of **line_qty**, the **product_sku** and the prod_category for every product. So you get a pseudo-table with three columns: the prod_sku, the **prod_category** and the sum of **line_qty**. Now you have to select the max and the min of **line_qty** grouping by **prod_category**. In a third step introduce the **state** and **quarter of year** as grouping criteria in the first select.
I am using my smartphone: I am very restricted. Tomorrow, inschaa Allah, I will provide a solution.

Comment: This is a faq. Before considering posting please read the manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Refect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can give that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table.

Answer (score 1):

You can join all related tables (using the *standard* syntax - with the `on` keyword), and group by product and quarter. Then you can use a window function to rank records within groups having the same `prod_category`, `cust_state` and quarter (this requires MySQL 8.0):

```
select *
fom (
    select
        p.prod_sku,
        b.brand_name,
        p.prod_category,
        c.cust_state,
        year(i.inv_date) yr,
        quarter(i.inv_date) qr,
        sum(l.prod_qty) sum_qty,
        rank() over(
            partition by p.prod_category, c.cust_state, year(i.inv_date), quarter(i.inv_date)
            order by sum(l.prod_qty) 
        ) rn_asc,
        rank() over(
            partition by p.prod_category, c.cust_state, year(i.inv_date), quarter(i.inv_date)
            order by sum(l.prod_qty) desc
        ) rn_desc
    from lgproduct p
    inner join lgline     l on l.prod_sku  = p.prod_sku
    inner join lginvoice  i on i.inv_num   = l.inv_num
    inner join lgcustomer c on c.cust_code = i.cust_code
    inner join lgbrand    b on b.brand_id  = p.brand_id
    group by
        p.prod_sku,
        b.brand_name,
        p.prod_category,
        c.cust_state,
        year(i.inv_date) yr,
        quarter(i.inv_date) qr,
) t
where rn_asc = 1 or rn_desc = 1
order by prod_category, cust_state, yr ,qr, sum_qty desc
```